# I need to get specific data from a website using inspect element

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm new to Python and I'm struggling to find a solution or a way to do the following thing. I need 2 things from a website that I can get from inspect element: the link to the .m3u8 file which can be found in the html (Elements tab) of the website and a link to a .ts file (it doesn't matter which one) from the Network tab. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Use BS4 and requests:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64828046/'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find(id='question-header')
print(results)
```

Comment: I get "None" when I run this. For some reason the m3u8 link is not inside page.content

Comment: Yes, it was a small example. You would have to edit it yourself to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import lxml.html
connection = urlopen('http://yourwebsite')

dom = lxml.html.fromstring(connection.read())
for link in dom.xpath('//a/@href'):
    if link.endswith(".m3u8") or link.endwith(".ts"):
        print(link)
```

you can use other `if conditions` to check whether something is in the link, like:

```
if "m3u8" in link:
   print(link)
```

Comment: I run this but I get nothing. I've replaced "yourwebsite" with my link but it won't work :(

Comment: can you give us your website link?